# Is there any way to get an analytic result for the distance between two circles' centers such that, in area, A∩B = (-A)∩B

Tags: trigonometry, implicit-function, algebra-precalculus

In solving for the distance, d, between two circles of equal radii as a function of that radius, r, such that the area in which they overlap is 1/3 the total area, I have wound up with the following expressions:

$d=2r\cos(\theta/2)$
$\theta-\sin \theta=\pi/2$

Where $\theta$ is the angle between two radii drawn from the center of either circle to the circles' intersection points.

This *sort of* solves the problem, but since $\theta$ has to be greater than $\pi/2$ the usual approximation $\theta=\sin\theta$ for small $\theta$ is inapplicable, and since sine is a transcendental function, without some sort of approximation like that there's no way to make the analytic solution not-ugly (as far as I can tell).

Is there something I can do here to get a more elegant expression?  Could I have gotten a more elegant expression if I did a better job solving the problem at an earlier point?

Comment: Since I'm doing this for fun on my own I don't know *for sure* that the math I've done so far isn't erroneous, though I've checked it over obvs.  Regardless, I'm not asking about the problem itself but the emergent problem of resolving this ?implicit? expression for theta.  I'm down to edit in correct expressions if it turns out something is wrong, but if an earlier error removes the fundamental issue at stake I'll instead remove/change the context.